# Change Java language's description on SO

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tag-wiki

The Java language description on SO is, well, pretty lackluster. Especially when compared to C, C++, and C#. It's time to update it to something more proper.

I happen to like this one pulled from wikipedia:

> Java is a general-purpose, concurrent, class-based, object-oriented
>   computer programming language that is specifically designed to have as
>   few implementation dependencies as possible. It is intended to let
>   application developers "write once, run anywhere" (WORA), meaning that
>   code that runs on one platform does not need to be recompiled to run
>   on another. Java applications are typically compiled to bytecode
>   (class file) that can run on any Java virtual machine (JVM) regardless
>   of computer architecture.

Comment: why the downvote? is this not the place to discuss these changes?

Comment: You know you can propose tag wiki changes from the tag itself? http://stackoverflow.com/edit-tag-wiki/17

Comment: I did not know that @JonW  - I will try that now. thanks!

Comment: Don't just paste it direct from Wikipedia uncredited though.

Comment: And don't use code markup for a (non-code) quote.

Comment: I did credit wikipedia in my OP

Comment: Keep in mind that tag descriptions aren't there to give you information about the language, they're to help people determine whether that tag should be applied to their question.  It's about defining the scope of that tag's use on SO, not about being an encyclopedia entry for that topic.

Comment: @Servy Yes I know, I just wanted it's snippet to be a bit better. If you read the C# one, it makes you think it's the bee's knee's. But if you read the Java snippet, "eh, it's another language". (you can tell the original authors favored C family lol!)

Comment: The job of a tag wiki is to describe the tag, not to advertise it. “Eh, it's another language” is a perfectly reasonable reaction.

Answer (score 12):

You're apparently worrying about the tag wiki excerpt, and the [suggestion you made](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3010574) is *way* too long to be an excerpt. An excerpt is meant to be a one to three line **summary** of what the tag is about, to help quickly direct people on proper usage of the tag without making them go to the full tag wiki to find out. A full paragraph from Wikipedia in there **is never appropriate**. Honestly, I don't see anything wrong with how it is right now. In fact, all of that information you edited into the excerpt is [already available in the full wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/info).

Further, I must discourage you from copy-pasting directly from Wikipedia. It is rarely ever appropriate because Wikipedia's information often includes useless information buried within useful information. Our tag wikis, as mentioned previously, are there to guide users on proper use of the tag, provide basic need-to-know knowledge about the tag, and direct them to further resources that they might find useful in programming. Including a full history lesson from Wikipedia is not something we care to have in our tag wiki. If a user wants a history lesson, they can follow the link to Wikipedia for that.

Comment: thank you for accepting my latest edit attempt. I feel it does Java a lot more justice now and is more comparable to the C family tag exerts.

Comment: btw - about half of the java tag's page article is taken directly from wikipedia, or wikipedia took half of it's page from SO's Java tag... lol.